# How to convert result of mysql query in json format in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

i want to convert the result of mysql query into format json

The query return a lot fo records but the print_r of json doesn't return anything

```
$sql="select concat(sig,doc)as Order,date,age from ordertable";
$res = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

$json = json_decode($rows, true);
fwrite($handle, "json: ".print_r($json,true)." \n\n");
```

Comment: `json_decode` take string as argument but you sending array. Perhaps you looking for: `fwrite($handle, "json: " . json_encode($rows) . " \n\n");`

Comment: Replace `$json = json_decode($rows, true);` by `$json = json_encode($rows, true);` ?

Comment: You've got your encoding and decoding mixed up. You need `json_encode()` to turn an array into a json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this below two lines as follows,

```
$json = json_encode($rows); // to convert it into json internal array
//$json = json_encode($rows,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); // to convert it json object
fwrite($handle, "json: $json \n\n");
```

This should do the trick.